# best way to store latest event data

Tags: python, database, postgresql, optimization, query-optimization

We are using an event-based system where are using postgres database to store the events audit. Currently to store latest entry for any event we are using postgres MATERIALIZED VIEW. For any event that modifies data we update the main event audit table and also refresh MATERIALIZED VIEW, but that is a very time consuming. We use the below python code to refresh view but it just drops the old view and recreates it which time consuming

```
await connection_pool.execute(
                    "REFRESH MATERIALIZED VIEW CONCURRENTLY events_current"
                )
```

I guess it is not the right way to handle, my approach is to create a new table and keep the latest data for an event there. Please let me know if that is fine, or if there is any better approach for the same.

Please let me know if any further information is required.

Comment: Why would you use a materialized view for this? Typically materialized views are used for returning denomralized complex data views that often require expensive calculations and thus can't be done in realtime. If you have a single table that has large amounts of data that storing in a single table is slowing it down, then you would want to look into partitioning. If you do need a materialized view then it is often necessary to do the updates via triggers on the underlying tables,

Comment: Thanks, @MichaelRobellard materialized view was an existing solution which obviously isn't good. That's why I am looking for a better solution. Partitioning the main table holding all the event audits isn't a good option as it holds all the event data, what I am looking for is a solution where I can just keep the latest data only for an event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A materialized view is not a bad solution, but only if you can regard it as "point in time" (beginning of business day, or within last 3 hours, ...). It is not a good solution for an "at this moment" requirement. Yours seems to be the latter.  
Your best option would be just creating a view that gets the latest data. If that is not viable, due to audit event size, then need to look elsewhere.  I am not a fan of creating a table to contains the latest data. That would be replicating the data, and  replicated data inevitability winds up being different. But a slight twist comes to mind: Create a table that contains only the event id and the event_audit log id, maintaining only the last audit id. Without your full table definition (ddl) I can only show a skeletal setup, but you should get the idea.

```
create table event_last_audits( 
             event_id integer 
           , ea_id    integer
           , constraint last_event_audits_pk primary key (event_id) 
           , constraint last_event_audits_2fk   
                        foreign key (ea_id)
                        references event_audits(ea_id)
           );
```

Yon can then maintain both the event_audit and the event_last_audit in the same trigger. Something like:

```
create or replace function  audit_events()
  returns trigger 
  language plpgsql
as $$
begin 
    with audit_rec( event_id, ea_id)  as 
         ( insert into event_audits(event_id, dml_action,old_status) 
               select new.event_id
                    , tg_op
                    , case when tg_op='INSERT'
                           then null 
                            else old.status 
                      end
             returning event_id, ea_id
         ) 
    insert into event_last_audits(event_id, ea_id) 
         select event_id, ea_id
           from audit_rec
             on conflict (event_id) 
             do update 
                    set ea_id = excluded.ea_id; 
     return new; 
end; $$; 
     
create trigger audit_events_aiur
       after insert or update on events 
       for each row 
       execute function audit_events();
```

See [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=41902697558b03d5db16268a76b9584c).

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Belayer it helps a lot but in my condition, we don't have any eventId to identify an event uniquely. We just have an event audit table containing all the events and each event gets uniquely identified based on some set of values. So the task is to push all the events into the event audit table and keep only the latest in the new table. Will try with trigger approach you have mentioned. Thanks :-)